# How to export different groups in same data source to different Excel workbooks?

Tags: r, loops

I currently have a tibble in R that I would like to export to excel but rather than exporting the entire tibble to one large workbook I want there to be separate workbooks, with each one corresponding to a distinct value in a grouping variable I have already defined.

For reproducibility, I will use the `iris` dataset as an example.  The end result I want is three separate workbooks, one for each species of iris, setosa, versicolor, and virginica,  each containing the sepal length and width, with the file name of each workbook corresponding to the species name, i.e., setosa.csv, versicolor.csv, and virginica.csv. The only way I can think of doing this is doing it one by one like so:

```
iris %>% 
filter(Species == "setosa") %>%
select(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width) %>%
write_csv(path = "setosa.csv")
```

Because my grouping variable has 50+ possible values (all character strings) it obviously isn't practical to do this one at a time. I thought I could possibly solve this using a loop, but I am not confident in my loop writing ability to even attempt that here.

Comment: Feel free to [accept any answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), if you are satisfied with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can separate the data.frame by `Species` into a list of data.frames and then use `sapply`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- iris %>% 
  split(f = iris$Species)

sapply(names(df), function(x) write_csv(df[[x]], file = paste0(x, ".csv")))
```

This should return your desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `purrr`. You start by splitting the data frame by the group column and then write each subset.

Here's a general function for it:

```r
save_groupwise <- function(data, group_col, path = ""){
  
  # Split into subsets
  splits <- split(x = data, f = data[[group_col]])
  
  # Save each subset
  purrr::map2(
      .x = splits,
      .y = names(splits),
      .f = function(.x, .y){
        readr::write_csv(.x, path = paste0(path, .y, ".csv"))
      }
    )
  
  # Don't return anything
  invisible()
}

iris %>% 
  save_groupwise("Species")
```